# Problem with updating DE record via SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, marketingcloudapi, updaterecord

When trying to update DE record via SSJS nothing gets updated, but I don't know which step is wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Here's the SSJS Code.

```
<script runat = "server" >
    
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

//token access
var authEndpoint = 'https://.auth.marketingcloudapis.com';
var payload = {
    client_id: "",
    client_secret: "",
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
    account_id: ""
};
var url = authEndpoint + '/v2/token';
var contentType = 'application/json';

var tokenResponse;
var accessToken;

try {
    var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
    if (accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
        tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
        accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token;
    }
} catch (error) {
    Write(Stringify(error));
}

var Journey_DE = DataExtension.Init("journeyMaster_test");
var Filter = {Property:"deleteFlag",SimpleOperator:"isNull"};
var data = Journey_DE.Rows.Retrieve(Filter);
var data_length = data.length;
var journey_name;
var journey_version;
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];

for (i = 0; i < data_length; i++) {
    journey_name = data[i].JourneyName;
    journey_version = parseInt(data[i].VersionNumber);
    var restEndpoint = 'https://.rest.marketingcloudapis.com';
    var url2 = restEndpoint + '/interaction/v1/eventDefinitions/?name=' + journey_name;
    var de_name;
    var retrieveContent;
    var item;
    var count;

    try {
        var result = HTTP.Get(url2, headerNames, headerValues);
        if (result.Status == 0) {
            retrieveContent = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Content);
            count = retrieveContent.count;
            item = retrieveContent.items[count-1];
            de_name = item.dataExtensionName;
           
        }
    } catch (error) {
        Write(Stringify(error));
        

    };

    var entryDE = DataExtension.Init(de_name);
    var entryFilter = {Property:"exitFlag",SimpleOperator:"isNull"};
    var entrydata = entryDE.Rows.Retrieve(entryFilter);
    var entrydata_length = entrydata.length;
        if (entrydata_length == 0) {
            var rows = Platform.Function.UpdateData("journeyMaster_test", ["JourneyName", "VersionNumber"], [journey_name, journey_version], ["deleteFlag"], ["true"]);
        };
 

}
</script>
```

Comment: The code works fine for me. What errors are you getting? Can you also enclose the update DE in a try/catch block

Comment: I tried to debugg with try/catch block via Cloudpage but I got 400 error.

Comment: I figured it out why it wasn't work. I didn't change the DE's externalkey used in DataExtension.Init("DE's externalKey"). Thanks for your kindnesss.